# Jupyter Notebook Sharing with IBM Cloud Pak

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud, watson-studio

I am trying to link a Jupyter Notebook from IBM Cloud Pak.

The issue is that this is registered (for my account) as a fully public, fully shared notebook for anyone with a link

The notebook opens to a single cell with In [  ]: and no content.

Is this a common issue?

Comment: Please provide more information. What steps did you perform? Is this a notebook created as asset in Watson Studio / Cloud Pak for Data?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a share link in CPD, you can select whether you want to share:

1. just cell output
2. cell output and non-sensitive code cells
3. cell output and all code cells

Note that the share link always points to the latest **version**, created with the "Save Version" menu item. If you created the initial version with only an empty cell, and didn't save a new version with more contents afterwards, users still see the empty cell. Just saving with "Save" isn't enough, you need to use "Save Version" to update the shared content.